# HTML5 Drag Release offsetX offsetY jump

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm playing with the HTML5 drag and drop and tracking the mouse position while dragging.

OffsetX and OffsetY works awesome until you release the mouse, the offsets jump to a negative number on the last drag event dispatched

here's the html:

```
<div id="dragger"></div>
<div id="console"></div>
```

here's the css:

```
#dragger{
    -webkit-user-drag: element;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: hsla(200, 100%, 50%, 0.4);
}​
```

and the js

```
$('#dragger').bind('drag', function (e) {
    $('#console').html(e.originalEvent.offsetX);
})​
```

You can also test out at http://jsfiddle.net/Eu2mz/5/

Also I'm just trying to get it to work in webkit for now.

Comment: 2014 I'm still seeing this. :(

Comment: I solved this by returning if  `e.originalEvent.y === 0`

Comment: 2018 I'm still seeing this

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why but when dragging over or dropping outside of the draggable object will change the `offsetX`, `offsetY`, `clientX`, `clientY` etc properties to some unintelligible number.

**The fix is to `preventDefault` on the document drop and dragover events.**

```js
document.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {
  var element = document.getElementById('console');
  element.textContent = event.clientX;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);

document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```css
#dragger{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: hsla(200, 100%, 50%, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" id="dragger" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)"></div>
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: That worked. But I don't know how. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and came up with a solution that will work 99.99999% of the time. the explanation is below:

## Solution (should work in every case your users will run into)

```
eng.window.addEventListener(
    "drag"
    ,function(event){
        //If both screenX and screenY are 0, likely the user just released.
        if(!event.screenX && !event.screenY) return;
        
        //Your code here
    }
);
```

## Explanation

I looked through the event returned on releasing the mouse and compared it to the event immediately before, and couldn't find anything that will work in 100% of the cases- there's no easy "buttonPressed" feature or the like hidden inside the object.

I did see though that every single measure of cursor position is changed when you release: `clientX`, `layerX`, `offsetX`, `pageX`, `screenX`, and regular `x`/`y`. They all default to the top-left value possible, which may be the top-left corner of the window- or the screen.

But what is the likelihood that your user will go into fullscreen mode drag and drop an element into the very top-left pixel of their screen? (In Chrome for me, `screenX` is actually set to the left edge of the window; but `screenY` takes Chrome's HUD into account)

So while the above won't work in that 1 fringe case (that your users will likely never-ever run into), it will work every other time.

Tested in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

### Google Chrome BUG: Be aware!

I am reporting this as of Chrome version 68.* and earlier so it may be fixed later on.
Been pulling my hair out for ages as I have two different computers, both with Windows 10 and the exact same version of Chrome.  On one, the HTML 5 ghost layer doesn't skip forward when you start to drag it yet (works perfectly) on the other computer it skips!

Finally discovered that this happens when you change the font size on your Windows Display Settings. (Right click on desktop -> Display Settings - > Scale and Layout).

If you change the font size to be anything other than 100% it messes up the ghost. I have a computer with a 4k monitor that needed 150% font size and my other stayed at 100%.

Doesn't seem to be happening in Opera or Edge and hav'nt had time to test all browsers.
I have already reported it to Google.

`Basic example`
http://jsfiddle.net/w9uyc5k4/

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your jsfiddle link appears to also be affected by the window size. Try it in it's own doc to narrow possibilities?

Comment: Alone it is also affected by window size.

Answer (score -1):

You can add drag end event it should solve the problem.
like this:

```
$('#dragger').bind('dragend', function (e) {
     $('#console').html(e.originalEvent.offsetX);
})
```

Comment: There is a delay when using drag end. I'll update the fiddle to demo it.

Comment: I updated it and you're right it works, but you can see if first snaps to a negative number then after a delay gives the correct final coordinate.  Weird stuff. http://jsfiddle.net/Eu2mz/16/