# onDrag event raised with incoherent values when mouse released

Tags: javascript, html

I am far from being an html/javascript expert and I am going crazy around this problem. Did not find anything on the net regarding this, I tried multiple things but without success.

Basically I am using drag functionality to achieve something. I don't really need the drag/drop, what I am just interested in is the drag.

Here is a very very simple sample illustrating my issue :

https://jsfiddle.net/fhdoLz70/2/

The div can be dragged around and I am logging the `event.clientX` value. The values are correct during the drag, but when I release the mouse, the `onDrag` event is raised once more with a incoherent `clientX` value (completely out of bounds, negative value). The same happens for `clientY` and probably other values associated with the event (not interested in other values but `clientX` and `clientY` so I haven't checked).

Why is `onDrag` raised when the mouse is released ? Drag is over ... And why does it hold such weird values ? How can I avoid to receive this last event on mouse release ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should post a minimal example here, it's much easier to respond and links may not last. The example does't exhibit the behaviour you describe.

Comment: His example does show the behavior he describes for me in Chrome. Also this has been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128216/html5-drag-release-offsetx-offsety-jump

Comment: I tried Safari and Omniweb, seemed to work OK. Didn't work at all in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is an oddity with jsfiddle. The ondrag event will be fired on release, but it typically would return zero. If you took your same code and placed it in a standalone file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DragTest</title>
    <style>
    .dragDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div draggable="true" class="dragDiv" ondrag="handleDrag(event)"/>
     <script>
     function handleDrag(evt){
          console.log(evt.clientX);
      }
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your console will log a 0 instead of the crazy number.
To catch the last event, keep in mind that there is an ondragend event fired on release. You could do handling there.

Comment: more correct: that is not an oddity but the negative values you end up with in jsfiddle represent the position of the iframe the code is executed in. Actually the values for x and y are reset to 0,0 but the coordinates returned are to be considered as relative to the top left of the iframe

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, could have turned in circle for hours while staying inside of jsfiddle trying to find a solution. Greatly appreciated !

Comment: A similar behaviour is exhibited in stackoverflow snippets.