# How to drag and transform a box?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a box where I can drag it along the X-axis of the page. I want to drag and drop it wherever. However, the code isn't working out, since `e.clientX` value resets itself after a new click. Thus I can drag it, but when I drag it again, it automatically goes to the middle.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
box.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
box.addEventListener("drag", handleDrag);
box.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
let startX = 0;

function dragStart(e) {
  startX = e.clientX;
  console.log(startX);
}

function handleDrag(e) {
  const currentX = e.clientX;
  box.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (currentX - startX) + 'px)';
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  box.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (e.clientX - startX) + 'px)';
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" draggable="true"></div>
</div>
```

[I've already noticed there are some bugs with the drag event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128216/html5-drag-release-offsetx-offsety-jump).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i think the solution is there :

What I have done is to add a property to the box (you could just declare a global variable if you have only one box) that **stores the current position of the box**

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
box.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
box.addEventListener("drag", handleDrag);
box.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
box.currentTransform = 0; // adding this 
let startX = 0;

function dragStart(e) {
  startX = e.clientX;
  console.log(startX);
}

function handleDrag(e) {
  const currentX = e.clientX;
  box.style.transform = 'translateX(' + 
    (box.currentTransform + currentX - startX) + // changed that
    'px)'; 
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  box.currentTransform += e.clientX - startX // added that
  box.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (box.currentTransform) + 'px)'; // changed this
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" draggable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Now it seems to work just fine

Comment: Thanks, that works indeed! What is .currentTransform? I don't see it in a variable anywhere